# How to download the source code from Ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have my app on Ionic View app, which also means that it is on ionic.io. Is there a way to download the source code?

Comment: Extract An Android APK And View Its Source Code is 
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/extract-android-apk-view-source-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is currently not possible. I don't think it will ever be possible.

What you can do, but only if it's your application and you can prove it. Come to the Ionic Official Forum, post a message kindly asking admins (not moderators, I'm one of them and I know I can't help you) if they can mail to you your app.

Or you can mail them here: help@ionic.io

Comment: Thanks, just contacted them.

Answer (score 0):

Did u get this resolved? I managed to download my latest code from ionic.io.

Click on your profile link at the top right of ionic.io, then go to the Data link on the left, enter your app id and click recover.

[image: download code link]

Comment: Under profile the Data link is not available. So I manually opened  https://apps.ionic.io/settings/data path and recovered by using App ID